# How do I keep my CSS button entirely within its parent DIV?

Tags: html, css, button

I'm having trouble keeping a custom link in my content area.  I have this HTML

```css
#createBtn {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #7ac9b7;
  background-color: #4180C5;
  color: aliceblue;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="userNotificationsWrapper">

  <p>You have no notifications.</p>

  <div><a id="createBtn" data-method="get" href="/user_notifications/new">Create Notification</a></div>

</div>
```

but the link/button keeps going over the bottom boundary of my content area (the DIV with id="userNotificationsWrapper").  I want the content area to capture the link/button entirely and I would like it to line up on the next line after my message.

I created a Fiddle to demonstrate my problem -- https://jsfiddle.net/b3hxko01/ .

Comment: can you please  explain with  image screen short  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. First is `width: calc(100% - 750px);` on `#userNotificationsWrapper`. You probably want to replace it with a `max-width: 220px` or similar...?

And the second one is `width: 100%;` on `#createBtn`. I'd replace it with:

```css
#createBtn {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}
```

Your [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3hxko01/1/). My CSS is added at the end. Haven't touched yours. Feel free to search each of the props and see what they do.

Answer (score -1):

Do you want something like this ? 
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nj0zxLmp/)

If not attach a screenshot of it pls .

Here's the css

```
#userNotificationsWrapper {
 margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #C7CDD1;
width: 75%;
font-family: Acme;
font-size: 18px;
height:100px;
padding-left: 10px;
```

}